# Fit wordy table on a Page

Tags: tables, tabularx, textwidth

This is what I try to do fit a wordy table on a page.

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}% http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ieeetran


\begin{document}
\begin{table}[]
    \centering
    \caption{My caption}
    \label{my-label}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
            \hline
        \textbf{Paper} & \textbf{Goal} & \textbf{Data} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Tool/Technology}} \\ \hline
        Security threats for big data: A study on Enron e-mail dataset & Mitigating Phishing Attacks & Enron E-mail Dataset & Enronic Software \\ \hline
        A Big Data architecture for security data and its application to phishing characterization & Defending Against Spam and Phishing & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}pcap\\ files, logs from honey net\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Hadoop,\\ Spark\end{tabular} \\ \hline
        Data mining methods for detection of new malicious executables & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Detect\\ malicious malware\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Malicious\\ and benign executable binaries\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Data\\ Mining Algorithms\end{tabular} \\ \hline
        A practical solution to improve cyber security on a global scale & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Security\\ monitoring Tool\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Network\\ flow\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Data\\ Mining Techniques, High Functioning autistic graduates\end{tabular} \\ \hline
        Automate Cybersecurity Data Triage by Leveraging Human Analysts' Cognitive Process & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Help\\ security analysts with data triage\end{tabular} & Securityanalysts' operation traces & Data mining Techniques, Humans \\ \hline
        Analyzing and Predicting Security Event Anomalies: Lessons Learned from a Large Enterprise Big Data Streaming Analytics Deployment & Improve SIEM by adding important features. & Traditional SIEM systems & Data Mining, Graph Analytics \\ \hline
        Study on Network Information Security Based on Big Data & APT Detection & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Network\\ data collection\end{tabular} & Big Data Analytics(BDA), Network event collection, Big Data correlation analysis \\ \hline
        Big data machine learning and graph analytics: Current state and future challenges & Combine batch and stream data processes for efficeincy & Hetereogeneous big data & Lambda architecture \\ \hline
        SIM in light of big data & Cyber attack detection & Security logs & Machine learning techniques \\ \hline
        Data fusion \& visualization application for network forensic investigation-a case study & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Network\\ forensic investigation\end{tabular} & Network logs & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Data\\ fusion techniques, visualization, Self Organizing Map\end{tabular} \\ \hline
        Owlsight: Platform for real-time detection and visualization of cyber threats & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Real\\ time detection and visualization of threats\end{tabular} & Heterogeneous network data & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}BDA,\\ web services, data visualization\end{tabular} \\ \hline
        Predicting and fixing vulnerabilities before they occur: a big data approach & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Proactive\\ (Prevention better than cure approach)\end{tabular} & Heterogeneous network data & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}BDA\\ techniques, machine learning\end{tabular} \\ \hline
        Machine learning classification model for Network based Intrusion Detection System & Network Intrusion Detection System in Android phones & Android OS data & Machine Learning Algorithms \\ \hline
        A big data architecture for large scale security monitoring & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Intrusion\\ detection and prevention systems\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}NetFlow\\ records, HTTP traffic and honeypot data\end{tabular} & Shark, Spark, machine learning algorithms \\ \hline
        A Scalable Meta-Model for Big Data Security Analyses & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Detect\\ network anomaly at per flow level rather than the usual per packet level which\\ tends to bring scalability issues\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Networkflow\\ data\end{tabular} & Machine learning and data mining algorithms \\ \hline
        Network security and anomaly detection with Big-DAMA, a big data analytics framework & Intrusion Detection System & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Network\\ flow Data\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Spark,\\ Cassandra, Machine Learning Algorithms\end{tabular} \\ \hline
        SHIELD: A novel NFV-based cybersecurity framework & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}SecaaS\\ to protect applications on software as service platform\end{tabular} & Heterogeneous Data & Big Data Analytics \\ \hline
        Security evaluation of RC4 using big data analytics & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Analysing\\ RC4 based on big data processing technique to analyse the security of RC4\end{tabular} & RC4 & MapReduce \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

This is the result I get.
[image]

How do I get this right?

Comment: You tagged [tag:tabularx].  Why aren't you using it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest the following solution using varibale width `tabularx` columns with flushleft alignment, `booktabs`'s horizontal lines and an `extrarowheight` as a giude to the eye. Additionally, `ragged2e`'s command `\RaggedRight` in the definition of the new column type allows for hyphenation in ragged text and works best when loading the appropriate hyphenation patterns by using `babel`.

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\RaggedRight\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}
\begin{document}
\begin{table*}[]
    \setlength\extrarowheight{5pt}
    \centering
    \caption{My caption}
    \label{my-label}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{RRRR}
    \toprule
    \textbf{Paper} & \textbf{Goal} & \textbf{Data} & \textbf{Tool/Technology} \\
    \midrule
        Security threats for big data: A study on Enron e-mail dataset & Mitigating Phishing Attacks & Enron E-mail Dataset & Enronic Software \\
        A Big Data architecture for security data and its application to phishing characterization & Defending Against Spam and Phishing & pcap files, logs from honey net & Hadoop, Spark \\
        Data mining methods for detection of new malicious executables & Detect malicious malware & Malicious and benign executable binaries & Data Mining Algorithms \\
        A practical solution to improve cyber security on a global scale & Security monitoring Tool & Network flow & Data Mining Techniques, High Functioning autistic graduates \\ 
        Automate Cybersecurity Data Triage by Leveraging Human Analysts' Cognitive Process & Help security analysts with data triage & Securityanalysts' operation traces & Data mining Techniques, Humans \\ 
        Analyzing and Predicting Security Event Anomalies: Lessons Learned from a Large Enterprise Big Data Streaming Analytics Deployment & Improve SIEM by adding important features. & Traditional SIEM systems & Data Mining, Graph Analytics \\ 
        Study on Network Information Security Based on Big Data & APT Detection & Network data collection & Big Data Analytics(BDA), Network event collection, Big Data correlation analysis \\ 
        Big data machine learning and graph analytics: Current state and future challenges & Combine batch and stream data processes for efficeincy & Hetereogeneous big data & Lambda architecture \\ 
        SIM in light of big data & Cyber attack detection & Security logs & Machine learning techniques \\ 
        Data fusion \& visualization application for network forensic investigation-a case study & Network forensic investigation & Network logs & Data fusion techniques, visualization, Self Organizing Map \\ 
        Owlsight: Platform for real-time detection and visualization of cyber threats & Real time detection and visualization of threats & Heterogeneous network data &BDA, web services, data visualization \\ 
        Predicting and fixing vulnerabilities before they occur: a big data approach & Proactive (Prevention better than cure approach) & Heterogeneous network data & BDA techniques, machine learning \\ 
        Machine learning classification model for Network based Intrusion Detection System & Network Intrusion Detection System in Android phones & Android OS data & Machine Learning Algorithms \\ 
        A big data architecture for large scale security monitoring & Intrusion detection and prevention systems& NetFlow records, HTTP traffic and honeypot data & Shark, Spark, machine learning algorithms \\
        A Scalable Meta-Model for Big Data Security Analyses & Detect network anomaly at per flow level rather than the usual per packet level which tends to bring scalability issues & Networkflow data & Machine learning and data mining algorithms \\ 
        Network security and anomaly detection with Big-DAMA, a big data analytics framework & Intrusion Detection System & Network flow Data & Spark, Cassandra, Machine Learning Algorithms \\ 
        SHIELD: A novel NFV-based cybersecurity framework & SecaaS to protect applications on software as service platform & Heterogeneous Data & Big Data Analytics \\ 
        Security evaluation of RC4 using big data analytics & Analysing RC4 based on big data processing technique to analyse the security of RC4 & RC4 & MapReduce \\ 
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `booktabs` doesn't define *vertical* lines :-) (actually it hate them).  probably `\RaggedRight` will work better, if some `babel` be defined.

Comment: @Zarko: Thanks for pointing this out. I never thought, I'd confuse horizontal and vertical but apparently it's friday...

Comment: i know, that was a typo. this happens to me too often :-(. i will erase my comments soon.

Answer (score 2):

You probably can't get it right easily... It's easy enough to make sure that your table stays within the page width: replace

```
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
```

with

```
\begin{tabular}{|p{.25\textwidth}|p{.25\textwidth}|p{.25\textwidth}|p{.25\textwidth}|}
```

to allow the lines to be wrapped within a cell.

But you use another level of tabulars within a lot of cells, and those do not respect the limits imposed by the outer tabular. You'll have to get rid of those nested tabulars (many seem to become superfluous when you change the column specification to a 'p{}'), or make sure they are constrained to the column width (tabular*).

Once you have solved that, you'll have to make sure the table can continue over two (or more) pages, which the tabular environment won't allow. For that, you'll have to use a package like xtab or longtable.

(note: it might be better to typeset the table in landscape orientation, but that won't make it fit on one page).

Answer (score 2):

one more alternative ...

- your table is to wide to be fit in one column. so it had to span two columns, i.e. be in `tabular*` environment
- for more "professional" look i would instead `\hline` use rules defined by package `booktabs`
- for tabular environment i suggest to exploit package `tabularx` (you tag it in your question). with it the table width can be set equal to text width and width of columns are automatically determined
- in case that the table has many rows, i will reduce font size to `\small`
- for more vertical spaces between rows in table i would exploit `\makegapedcells` macro from `makecell` package

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}% http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ieeetran
\usepackage{booktabs,
            makecell,   % <--- added
            tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\setcellgapes{5pt}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{afterpage}

\usepackage{lipsum}% for dummy text when needed

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{sidewaystable*}
    \centering
    \caption{My caption}
    \label{my-label}
\makegapedcells
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ *{4}{X} }% here is defined number of collumns
    \toprule
\thead{Paper}  & \thead{Goal} & \thead{Paper} & \thead{Goal}    \\
    \midrule
\lipsum*[11]    & \lipsum*[11]  & \lipsum*[12]      & \lipsum*[11]  \\
\lipsum*[11]    & \lipsum*[11]  & \lipsum*[11]      & \lipsum*[11]  \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{sidewaystable*}
\lipsum\lipsum
\end{document}
```

this mwe gives:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You will need the following packages: `tabularx` and `booktabs` for `tabularx` environment and `rotating` to use `sidewaystable` environment.

The environment `tabularx` allows the column sizes to be adjusted in such a way that they will occupied only a given width such as `\columnwidth` or `\textwidth` or even a fraction of them such as `0.9\columnwidth`. Your table is better handled if it was rotated by 90 degrees and occupy a whole page alone. This is why you `sidewaystable` environment.

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}% http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ieeetran

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{ >{ \arraybackslash \RaggedRight } X }
\newcolumntype{C}{ >{ \arraybackslash \Centering } X }
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable*}[]
    \centering
    \caption{My caption}
    \label{my-label}
    \begin{tabularx}{1\textwidth}{|L|L|L|L|}
        \hline
        \textbf{Paper} & \textbf{Goal} & \textbf{Data} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Tool/Technology}} \\ \hline
        Security threats for big data: A study on Enron e-mail dataset & Mitigating Phishing Attacks & Enron E-mail Dataset & Enronic Software \\ \hline
        A Big Data architecture for security data and its application to phishing characterization & Defending Against Spam and Phishing & \begin{tabular}[C]{@{}L@{}}pcap\\ files, logs from honey net\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[C]{@{}L@{}}Hadoop,\\ Spark\end{tabular} \\ \hline
        Data mining methods for detection of new malicious executables & \begin{tabular}[C]{@{}L@{}}Detect\\ malicious malware\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[C]{@{}L@{}}Malicious\\ and benign executable binaries\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[C]{@{}L@{}}Data\\ Mining Algorithms\end{tabular} \\ \hline
        A practical solution to improve cyber security on a global scale & \begin{tabular}[C]{@{}L@{}}Security\\ monitoring Tool\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[C]{@{}L@{}}Network\\ flow\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[C]{@{}L@{}}Data\\ Mining Techniques, High Functioning autistic graduates\end{tabular} \\ \hline
        Automate Cybersecurity Data Triage by Leveraging Human Analysts' Cognitive Process & \begin{tabular}[C]{@{}L@{}}Help\\ security analysts with data triage\end{tabular} & Securityanalysts' operation traces & Data mining Techniques, Humans \\ \hline
        Analyzing and Predicting Security Event Anomalies: Lessons Learned from a Large Enterprise Big Data Streaming Analytics Deployment & Improve SIEM by adding important features. & Traditional SIEM systems & Data Mining, Graph Analytics \\ \hline
        Study on Network Information Security Based on Big Data & APT Detection & \begin{tabular}[C]{@{}L@{}}Network\\ data collection\end{tabular} & Big Data Analytics(BDA), Network event collection, Big Data correlation analysis \\ \hline
        Big data machine learning and graph analytics: Current state and future challenges & Combine batch and stream data processes for efficeincy & Hetereogeneous big data & Lambda architecture \\ \hline
        SIM in light of big data & Cyber attack detection & Security logs & Machine learning techniques \\ \hline
        Data fusion \& visualization application for network forensic investigation-a case study & \begin{tabular}[C]{@{}L@{}}Network\\ forensic investigation\end{tabular} & Network logs & \begin{tabular}[C]{@{}L@{}}Data\\ fusion techniques, visualization, Self Organizing Map\end{tabular} \\ \hline
        Owlsight: Platform for real-time detection and visualization of cyber threats & \begin{tabular}[C]{@{}L@{}}Real\\ time detection and visualization of threats\end{tabular} & Heterogeneous network data & \begin{tabular}[C]{@{}L@{}}BDA,\\ web services, data visualization\end{tabular} \\ \hline
        Predicting and fixing vulnerabilities before they occur: a big data approach & \begin{tabular}[C]{@{}L@{}}Proactive\\ (Prevention better than cure approach)\end{tabular} & Heterogeneous network data & \begin{tabular}[C]{@{}L@{}}BDA\\ techniques, machine learning\end{tabular} \\ \hline
        Machine learning classification model for Network based Intrusion Detection System & Network Intrusion Detection System in Android phones & Android OS data & Machine Learning Algorithms \\ \hline
        A big data architecture for large scale security monitoring & \begin{tabular}[C]{@{}L@{}}Intrusion\\ detection and prevention systems\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[C]{@{}L@{}}NetFlow\\ records, HTTP traffic and honeypot data\end{tabular} & Shark, Spark, machine learning algorithms \\ \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{sidewaystable*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
\begin{tabular}{|p{0.25\textwidth}|p{0.25\textwidth}|p{0.25\textwidth}|p{0.25\textwidth}|}
```

Comment: Please make your answer self-contained with a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) and maybe a picture of the output.

Comment: @chortisho: Due to the white space on the left and right of each table column, your suggestion still adds up to more than the `textwidth`. Loading the `calc` package, one could use `p{0.25\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}` instead. Still the table is too wide as the vertical lines also occupy some horizontal space that is not taken into account.